# Faucet Atomizers and Aerators - Volume Flow Rate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

It is said that atomization nozzles and aerators in the faucet save water.
They reduce the volume flow rate of the nozzle. If this is true then isn't the equation of continuity violated?

For example, conventional faucets dispense around 6 litre/min of water and these atomizers dispense around 0.5 litre/min of water. This means that the inlet flow rate of the atomizer/aerator is 6 litre/min and outlet is 0.5 litre/min. How can this be possible?

I am working on a project on faucet atomizers and this issue has really got me into a knot.
I'd like you to have a look at my calculations as well just to check once.

Thanks !

Comment: Re, "This means that the inlet flow rate of the atomizer/aerator is 6 litre/min and outlet is 0.5 litre/min." No. It doesn't mean that at all. It just means that with the valve wide open, and with typical residential water pressure, it won't allow more than half a liter per minute to flow.

Comment: Yes sir, that's what i want to understand. This way, isn't the equation of continuity being violated(i.e. volume flow rate is same as each cross section)?

Comment: The flow rate in is the same as the flow rate out. When the manufacturer says, "it reduces the flow rate," they mean that the flow rate with the aerator installed will be less than the flow rate without it installed.

Comment: Alright, so if an aerator has an outlet volume flow rate of 0.5 litre/min, it means the inlet volume flow rate of the aerator will be 0.5 litre/min only?

Comment: That is correct.